# Data Transfer to a DataSet in vb.net

Tags: .net, windows, vb.net, visual-studio

I have 7 variables and i need to transfer them in a dataset 
I have already create the file with extension .xsd and i have already a report file .rdlc
I see the Dataset "DataTable"in my rdlc file but i can't see any field 
It gives me error of "No Dataset is Linked to the document"
From the other hand it sees the dataset in the selection dataset !!!
So at this point I'm completely confused
Please is there anybody which can assist me?

Comment: what are you exactly trying to do? if you create the dataset and datatable via code then you add 7 columns and 1 row with your 7 variables it should work, or are you designing the dataset in Visual Studio and not at execution time? in this case can't you simply use the dataset designer?

Comment: @Davide Piras, I'm in the second case, and the desiner didn't give me what i want, so i need to load these variables at run time into the rdlc document !!

Comment: if you design certain dataset then instantiate it by code and call WriteXml to have it on the disk as XML, you can then change that one and load it again. the saved one will help as an example and with incremental changes you could get where you want to be. Does it help?

Comment: @Davide Piras, Actually these 7 variables are coming from a form. If you are try to open a DataSet document from visual studio 2010 then you will see that you may open a dataset. Well I do that and I fill 7 columns with 7 names. Now what I want to do is to pass the 7 variables to those 7 columns, of course in one row. After That I need to read the DataSet from a reporting file .rdlc and take these variables in the final reporting form. That is what I want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a Dataset seems like overkill (you can use anything that is IEnumerable) but if you just want to add a row in a DataSet using code you simiply create an instance and call the Add Method on the Tables Row collection.

```
    Dim ds As TestDS = New TestDS()

    ds.YourTableName.Rows.Add(txtInputA.Text,
                          txtInputB.Text,
                          txtInputC.Text,
                          txtInputD.Text, 
                          txtInputE.Text,
                          txtInputF.Text,
                          txtInputG.Text

                         )
```

Then you can just add it to the DataSources collection

```
    lr.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("Variables", ds))
```

Comment: @Conrad Frix, Thank you for your answer, but please tell me few words about the last line. I mean the addition to the datasource

Comment: @Lefteris I assumed that you were using the Report in the same [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webforms/ReportViewer.aspx)  described. That said the `Rows.Add` method will work if you're using a BindingSource as well.

Comment: @Conrad I was confused with "lr.DataSources" because that drives as to another path.

Comment: @Conrad  What did you mean with the string "Variables"?

Comment: @Lefteris. Thats the arbitrary name I gave the datasource see the [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms251736(v=VS.80).aspx) on that constructor

Comment: @Conrad OK so Thats the DataSourse Name